# Crawl multiple page using Selenium and for loop

Tags: python, pandas, selenium, web-crawler

I want to crawl data in first 30 pages of a site and the output expected is a Dataframe but it crawl page 1 only.

my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('-headless')
options.add_argument('-no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('-disable-dev-shm-usage') 

url = "https://bonbanh.com/oto/page,"
data = []
for i in range(1,10):
    driver.get(url + str(i))
    x=driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div/div[6]/div[4]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]").text
    print(x)
    elements = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".cb1")
    types = [el.text for el in elements]
    elements = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".cb2_02")
    names = [el.text for el in elements]
    elements = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".cb3")
    prices = [el.text for el in elements]
    elements = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".cb4")
    address = [el.text for el in elements]
    df = pd.DataFrame({'TEN_XE':names,'LOAI_XE':types, 'GIA_XE': prices, 'DIA_CHI': address}) 
    data.append(df)
```

i dont know why it crawl data page 1 only. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here with this code

```
types = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".cb1")
types = [el.text for el in elements]
```

as your `elements` is not defined, you need to change it

```
year = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".cb1")
types = [el.text for el in year]
```

Comment: ah sorry, i edited my code. elements= driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".cb1"). The problem is how make it crawl all page in for loop. I dont know why it doesnt append the data

Comment: it seems to be working fine for me. What error you are getting?

Comment: it is not an error. my purpose is collect data from 30 pages of this site but my code only collect 21 rows from 1st page.